# some hard questions

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my table:

```
date             time   
6/24/2018   13:42:21    
6/24/2018   22:43:42    
6/26/2018   9:32:41       
6/26/2018   14:45:32    
6/27/2018   15:04:21    
6/27/2018   19:05:44    
6/28/2018   2:03:44     
6/28/2018   4:05:44        
6/28/2018   15:05:44    
6/28/2018   20:03:32
6/29/2018   9:04:06       
6/29/2018   21:06:32    
6/30/2018   4:50:33      
6/30/2018   14:44:33    
6/30/2018   21:33:44
```

it describes the time and the date that people enter the building i need to get a table like this:

```
arrival date    arrival time    leaving date    leaving time
6/24/2018       13:42:21        6/24/2018       22:43:42
6/26/2018       9:32:41         6/26/2018       14:45:32
6/27/2018       15:04:21        6/28/2018       4:05:44
6/28/2018       15:05:44        6/28/2018       20:03:32
6/29/2018       9:04:06         6/30/2018       4:50:33
6/30/2018       14:44:33        6/30/2018       21:33:44
```

the real problem is if some one is exiting the buildig between 00 to 04 in the morning it need to be in the table as leaving time

i tried this:

```
SELECT t1.tfullname,
       t1.arrival_date,
       ks.arrival_time_new,
       t1.leaving_date,
       t1.leaving_time
FROM (SELECT MIN(arrival_day) AS arrival_time_new,
             arrival_date,
             tFullName
      FROM dbo.DB
      WHERE DATEPART(hh, arrival_day) NOT BETWEEN 00 AND 05
      GROUP BY arrival_date,
               tFullName) ks
     JOIN (SELECT tFullName,
                  arrival_date,
                  MIN(arrival_day) AS arrival_time,
                  MAX(leaving_day) AS leaving_time,
                  CASE
                       WHEN LEAD(DATEPART(hh, MIN(arrival_day)), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY tfullname) BETWEEN 00 AND 04 THEN LEAD(leaving_date, 1, leaving_date) OVER (ORDER BY tfullname)
                       ELSE leaving_date
                  END AS leaving_date,
                  CASE
                       WHEN LEAD(DATEPART(hh, MIN(arival_day)), 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY arrival_date) BETWEEN 00 AND 04 THEN LEAD((SELECT MAX(leaving_day) AS leaving_time
                                                                                                                                FROM dbo.db
                                                                                                                                WHERE DATEPART(hh, arival_day) BETWEEN 00 AND 05
                                                                                                                                GROUP BY leaving_date,
                                                                                                                                         arrival_date),
                                                                                                                               1,
                                                                                                                               MAX(leaving_day)) OVER (ORDER BY arrival_date)
                       ELSE MAX(leaving_day)
                  END AS leaving_time
           FROM dbo.DB
           GROUP BY arrival_date,
                    leaving_date,
                    tFullName) t1 ON t1.arrival_date = ks.arrival_date
ORDER BY DATEPART(yy, t1.arrival_date),
         t1.arrival_date;
```

and it caused this problem:

SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
  another 2 tbles for example:

input

```
names   date    time
Shh 6/6/2018    10:24
Iii     6/6/2018    10:34
Rrr 6/6/2018    10:55
Shh 6/6/2018    21:34
Iii     6/6/2018    22:34
Rrr 6/6/2018    22:55
Rrr 6/7/2018    3:34
```

output

```
names   arrival date    arrival time    leaving_date    leaving time
Shh 6/6/2018    10:24   6/6/2018    21:34
Iii 6/6/2018    10:34   6/6/2018    22:34
Rrr 6/6/2018    10:55   6/7/2018    3:34
```

how can i solve this problem??

Comment: After formatting your SQL to something readable; There's a `,` After your `FROM`.

Comment: it isnt the problem this my mistake

Comment: IS that actually a copy of your code then?

Comment: yes it is but i accedently press the , button . i edited this and now its ok would you please help me?

Comment: @o.b: if a person leaves at time 5:00:01, where should it be counted?

Comment: it counts like he enters to te building

Comment: for 6/28/2018     ,6/30/2018  why the result is changing i will give one solution check it once 
SELECT DATE,   MAX(CASE 
  WHEN RN = 1
   THEN TIME
  END )AS FF ,DATE AS DATE2
 ,min(CASE 
  WHEN RN >1
   THEN TIME
  END) AS FF2
FROM (
 SELECT *
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY DATE
   ) AS RN
 FROM #TABLE2
 ) A
 GROUP BY DATE

Comment: it changes because he left at te 28/6 at 4 am but he came back at 3 pm

Comment: No for all records  starting time is coming as first but 28 and 30 it is not coming as expected i need explanation

Comment: at the 30/6 he left the building at 4 am and came back at 14 thats why 4am is a leaving time for the 27/6

Comment: where do i need to enter your query

Comment: i checked your query but id doesnt what i meant when people exsit the building between 00 an 04 it counts like they exsit in the dat before like i showed in the example table, i want my table to be organize exactly like the the second table is, can you help me please @Chanukya

Comment: @o.b What is the data type for the columns mentioned above? is there a primary key for the table (userid/employeeid)?

Comment: the data type is daetime and there isnt a primary key

Comment: @o.b please check my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very complex. It is a quick answer... Will try to work on an optimized query.

But the result is as per your expectation

```
;WITH cte AS(

            SELECT date,
                    time,
                    DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108))) AS Col3,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
                        CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108)))
                        ORDER BY DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108)))
                        ) AS RN,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
                        CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108)))
                        ORDER BY DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108))) DESC
                        ) AS RN1,
                    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108))) AS Date1
            FROM Table1
            )

SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.date AS [arrival date],T1.time AS [arrival time],
    T2.date AS [leaving date],T2.time AS [leaving time]
FROM cte AS T1
INNER JOIN cte AS T2
    ON T1.Date1=T2.Date1
WHERE T1.RN=1
    AND T2.RN1=1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99e5a/1)

--Edit After question changed:

```
;WITH cte AS(

            SELECT names,
                    date,
                    time,
                    DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108))) AS Col3,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
                        names,CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108)))
                        ORDER BY DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108)))
                        ) AS RN,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
                        names,CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108)))
                        ORDER BY DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108))) DESC
                        ) AS RN1,
                    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MINUTE,-299,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date,112)+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),time,108))) AS Date1
            FROM Table2
            )

SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.names,
    T1.date,T1.time,
    T2.date,T2.time
FROM cte AS T1
INNER JOIN cte AS T2
    ON T1.Date1=T2.Date1
    AND T1.names=T2.names
WHERE T1.RN=1
    AND T2.RN1=1
ORDER BY T1.date
```

[SQL Fiddle 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78f99/1)

Comment: what is the col1 and col2

Comment: Replace `col1` as `date` and `col2` as `time`

Comment: it looks very good i just need another qwestion i forgot to add in my qwestion the name of the person where i need to enter in the query the name of the person

Comment: U can use a `where` clause at this point `FROM Table1
           WHERE person=??
            )`

Comment: there is a problem the query shows the frst entrence and the last for each day . i want it to be the first and the last entrance for each person and each date can you help me

Comment: Can you give me an example of data for the same?

Comment: 5 minutes and i will give you i will add it to the qwestion

Comment: i enterred 2 more tables take a look at them ill be more then happy if you would help

Comment: @o.b I have modified the answer. Please accept it as a answer if it works for you!

Comment: it allmost works just 1 more thing how can i order it by a date?

Comment: @o.b Please check it as a answer if it worked for you.

Comment: 1 more qwestion how can i display it as a varchar @Luv

Comment: Do you mean  

**`CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T1.date,103),CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),T1.time),
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),T2.date,103),CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),T2.time) ??`**

Comment: Why minus 229 mins? Is there any logic behind it?

Comment: `299` because as OP, anything before 5:00 should be counted in previous day

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the semantic of a row (is it in or is it out) is entirely dependent by it's position ordered by `date` and `time`. If that is true, this should be solvable using `row_number()` and modulo 2 (as every second row (in the order) is an out record). That is, join all rows where the row number modulo 2 is 1 with the row where the row number is equal to the row number of the other row plus 1.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT date,
       time,
       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date,
                                   time) rn;
       FROM elbat
)
SELECT cte1.date [arrival date],
       cte1.time [arrival time],
       cte2.date [leaving date],
       cte2.time [leaving time]
       FROM (SELECT cte.date,
                    cte.time,
                    cte.rn
                    FROM cte
                    WHERE cte.rn % 2 = 1) cte1
            LEFT JOIN cte cte2
                      ON cte2.rn = cte1.rn + 1;
```

Comment: thanks but it doesnt the right answer on a bigger table like my table when i have 1000000 rows it cant work but thanks for your help

Comment: @o.b: It will work the same way on any table with the same structure regardless of the size of the table. If your question is actually on optimization, you should clarify this by editing your question or maybe better by asking a new one.